# Trying to pass a file along with it's path in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'am trying to get specific(*.csv) files in a directory along with it's whole path into a variable after i say `$files=Get-Childitem -path "E:\testimport\inbound\treas\" -filter "*.csv"`.

say, i have csv files like in `E:\testimport\inbound\treas\myfile1.csv,myfile2.csv..`

how would i return back
`E:\testimport\inbound\treas\myfile1.csv`
`E:\testimport\inbound\treas\myfile2.csv`
`E:\testimport\inbound\treas\myfile12.csv` into a seperate variable

Answer (score 0):

Get property `FullName` from objects

```
Get-ChildItem -Path \temp -Filter *.cvs | Select-Object -Property FullName
```

Comment: It works, Thanks!!, what if i had to skip the first three lines in the output and only get the files along with the paths

Comment: It works, Thanks!!, what if i had to skip the first three lines in the output and only get the files along with the paths. i'am trying like `Get-ChildItem -Path \temp -Filter *.cvs | Select-Object -Property FullName | Select-Object -skip 3` but i'am not getting the desired results, Any tip?

Comment: if i had to skip the _first three lines_ in the output: `Get-ChildItem -Path \temp -Filter *.cvs | Select-Object -Property FullName -Skip 3`, or if i have _to get files only_: `Get-ChildItem -Path \temp -Filter *.cvs | ? { ! $_.PSIsContainer } | Select-Object -Property FullName`